# VLC 3.0.2 compile fails under Ubuntu 18.04 for Win32

Tags: winapi, compilation, vlc, libvlc, mingw32

I am trying to compile VLC 3.0.2 according to the wiki document

https://wiki.videolan.org/Win32Compile/

The platform is a Ubuntu 18.04 64bit desktop and the target is Win32.

However, as I follows the instruction

```
$ ../extras/package/win32/configure.sh --host=HOST-TRIPLET --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

The compile shows error message as:

```
checking neaacdec.h usability... yes 
checking neaacdec.h presence... yes 
checking for neaacdec.h... yes 
checking for NeAACDecOpen in -lfaad... no
configure: error: cannot find FAAD library
```

As I go through the config.log file, I found the following message:

```
/home/zhengdao/develop/gitroot/pctools/mptool/vlc-3.0.2/contrib/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libfaad.a(syntax.o): In function `latmAudioMuxElement': /home/jenkins/workspace/vlc-nightly/vlc-nightly-win32-x86/contrib/contrib-win32/faad2/libfaad/syntax.c:2578: undefined reference to `_imp____acrt_iob_func'
```

So actually libfaad is not missing, but contains symbols that the compiler could not link against.

I can use previous old libraries that doesn't contain this symbol to work around, but will always encounter this error message here and there, and finally old libraries will be lack of APIs that VLC depends on, and the compile still fails.

Can anyone give me some guide to make the compile pass?

Answer (score 0):

Try to start with /extras/package/win32/build.sh . This script automatically build all the libraries and then it can build vlc itself.